# Command line switch to open Excel Template as a Workbook

Tags: excel, command-line-arguments

We have a shortcut (.lnk file) to an Excel 2010 Template (.xlxt file), with the following target specified:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE" "\\MyPath\MySpreadsheet.xltx"
```

However, opening this shortcut opens the Template version of the file. We need it to open the Workbook version (as if someone had right-clicked on the file itself and selected 'New'.

Does anybody a command line switch I can add to the target above to force the file to open as a Workbook.

Many thanks for any help,

Martin

Answer (score 2):

Removing the call to EXCEL.EXE has solved this.

So, the following target:

"\MyPath\MySpreadsheet.xltx"

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced the "excel.exe" call and it works like a charm. The template generates a new workbook derivated from.

```
//   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Excel.exe", @"C:\Book1.xltm");
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Book1.xltm");
```

I have placed a automatic start of the VBA macro into the workbook module on Open event.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Module1.Macro1

End Sub
```

And the action is executed for any workbook generated from the template at start.

So few lines of code, but efficient.

---

An alternative is to use the official command line arguments : /t  workbook path | file name

Starts Excel and opens the specified file as a template.

Example

```
excel.exe /t "c:\My Folder\book_name.xlsx".
```

See reference :
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Command-line-switches-for-Excel-321cf55a-ace4-40b3-9082-53bd4bc10725

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Excel.exe", @" /t C:\Book1.xltm");